# How to download video from url and hide/secure this video from other apps and Gallery

Tags: java, android

One part of my current project is downloading Videos from URL then saving to SDCard. But the problem is all of saved videos in sdcard is displayed in android gallery page. What I want is "I don't want all of my saved vidoes in android gallery."

Comment: 2 options: Either add a `.nomedia` file to the folder you are downloading to or start the folder you are saving to with a dot (`.`).

Comment: Hi GaiantTree thanks for reply. But the video file in side .nomedia not shows in gallery but then device connect to pc then open sdcard the files inside .nomedia folder show. So please let me know how can i protect

Comment: You mean you want to protect your files? Then you need to look into privacy/vault-like apps that encrypt your files and make them unreadable for others. Usually a dor (`.`) in front of the folder name hides it when using MTP.

Comment: Hi GiantTree Can you share some blog and tutorial or example for that if is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.nomedia` file inside the folder you don't want to be tracked by the MediaScanner. Maybe you'll need to rename the folder name after creating the file, since there is a bug that the MediaScanner (in some versions of android, not sure which one) fails to forget already-indexed files when it encounters a .nomedia file.

Comment: Hi Massita thanks for reply. But the video file in side .nomedia not shows in gallery but then device connect to pc then open sdcard the files inside .nomedia folder show. So please let me know how can i protect

Comment: Create a hidden folder, adding a dot `.` before the folder's name. So, if you have a folder named `Movies`, you have to change it to `.Movies`, so, this folder will be hidden.